# You have requested a non-existent service "Users_Users". Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony

When I try to access at my service, got this error :

> You have requested a non-existent service "Users_Users".

But the namespace, the name of the class, name of the file, name of folder is ok. I have already copy paste the name to be sure.

Controller ->

```
<?php

namespace UsersBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use UsersBundle\Form\UsersForm;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class UsersController extends Controller
{        
    public function UsersAction($Id)
    {
        $Users = $this->container->get('Users_Users')->ListeUsers($Id);
        return $this->render('UsersBundle:Users:users.html.twig', array('Users' => $Users));
    }
```

Service :

```
<?php

namespace UsersBundle\Services;

class Users
{  
    public function __construct($ldap,$Core_ConnexionsBDD,$MySql_ConnexionsBDD, $session)
    {
        $this->ldap = $ldap;
        $this->Core_ConnexionsBDD = $Core_ConnexionsBDD;
        $this->MySql_ConnexionsBDD = $MySql_ConnexionsBDD;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function ListeUsers($Id)
    {  
        $lists = $this->MySql_ConnexionsBDD->getUsers();
        return $lists->Liste($Id); 
    }

}
```

Un the service file, no problem, it's a copy paste of the

> get('Users_Users')

Where is the problem? I use the same method for my 4 other bundle :/

Comment: You might want to add the service definition to the question.

Comment: A service on symfony is a file where all calculations, data recovery and modification are done. It serves not to do at times two functions that do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Type in console "php bin/console debug:container", your service "Users_Users" and class name "UsersBundle\Services\Users" should be in response.

Comment: I don't have any Users_Users: / But I don't know where to look for them

Comment: When people ask for the service definitions they are talking about a file typically called services.yaml or .yml or .xml.  It contains the definitions of services, not the services themselves.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html but be sure to follow the docs for your particular Symfony version.  Quite a few differences between autowire and manual.

Comment: I got nothing in my app/services.yml. I'll remake my bundle with the doc and we'll see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app/config.yml missing import :

```
   - { resource: "@UsersBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```

Content of UsersBundle/Resources/config/services.yml :

```
services:

Users_Users:
    class: UsersBundle\Services\Users
    arguments: ["@Core_ConnexionsBDD","@MySql_ConnexionsBDD","@session"]
```

Comment: can you give the content of `@UsersBundle/Resources/config/services.yml` please ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide the service definition ? You know in a `yaml` or an `xml` file.

Then, please check the name of your service is really `Users_Users` (which is, in my mind a weird name).

If you named your service like the best practice encourages to do (`with the Full Qualified Class Name (FQCN)` -> [Read](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html#services-naming-and-format)):

```
#app/config/services.yml
services:
    UsersBundle\Services\Users:
        class: Acme\TwitterClient
        arguments: ["@someLdapServiceName", "@Another/Good/Named/Service", "@..."]
```

then your service will be able by its name:

```
<?php
    $this->get('UsersBundle\Services\Users');
```

From Symfony 2.8 and in Symfony v3.3 by default, a great new feature is the [Service autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html). You can use it to ease the service definition but you need to pay attention because since the 3.3 version, the default service auto-configuration comes with default private services:

`services:
    _defaults:
        public: false`

Please note also that in the next LTS 3.4 version and in 4.0, the services are private by default, no more need this configuration line.

So if you want to access your service directly from your container's get method, you'll need to add this to your `Users_Users` service definition:

`services:
    Users_Users:
        ...
        public: true`

Comment: A service on symfony is a file where all calculations, data recovery and modification are done. It serves not to do at times two functions that do exactly the same thing. Why Users_Users ? The norme of my society. I tried to do what you told me, but nothing changed: (

Comment: @Verdouze  I've updated my answer, you may need to set your service public if your default configuration set the default behavior to private (by default since 3.3)

Comment: Okay, if I ever have a problem, I'll try this solution ;)